# How to properly connect classes (Stack overflow in constructors)

Tags: java, class, constructor, instances

I'm relatively new to Java and I'm coding extensions/plugins for online game Minecraft.

I've recently started "bigger" projects which require more classes to preserve neatness.
I am still trying to fully understand how constructors work, but most recent try resulted into Stack Overflow (one constructor calling another, in loop).

In my case, for example, I have two classes,  `Main` and `MySQL`.

Main class initializes plugin, MySQL class contacts database and returns data to any class which calls it.

Example problematic code:

`Main.java`

```
class Main extends JavaPlugin {

    private final MySQL mysql = new MySQL();

    //Method which is called first 
    void onEnable(){

        //Just an example of initializing
        mysql.init();
        mysql.open();
    }
}
```

`MySQL.java`

```
class MySQL {

    private final Main main = new Main();

    void init(){}
    void open(){}
}
```

I know what the problem is, I just don't know proper solution, which would work with even more classes.

Also if I would have another class, main would connect to MySQL, another class would communicate with it, I should do something like *main.mysql.method* ?

Simplified, easy to understand explanation on how constructors and instances ("new" keyword) work would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: why do you need Main instance in MySQL ?

Comment: In main class, there's a method which alerts specific users about error, so I have to call _main.mysqlErrors_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, just as a pointer for future applications, you might want to take a look at [Design Patterns](http://www.javaworld.com/columns/jw-java-design-patterns-index.html), they tend to make design cleaner and easier to maintain.

In your case you have created a [Circular Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference). The easiest way to get around it would be to make something like so:

```
class Main extends JavaPlugin {

    private final MySQL mysql;

    public Main(MySQL mysql)
    {
        this.mysql = mysql
    }

    //Class which is called first 
    void onEnable() {

        //Just an example of initializing
        mysql.init();
        mysql.open();
    }
}

class MySQL {

    private final Main main = new Main(this);

    void init(){}
    void open(){}
}
```

This *should* solve the problem.

That being said, I am assuming that the `MySQL` class will have database related mechanisms. Such mechanisms are usually exposed through a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) design pattern. This design pattern should allow you to access the methods within the `MySQL` class only when you need them, thus also avoiding the circular reference issue.

Comment: Thanks for an answer, however does _private final MySQL mysql;_ call MySQL class which than initializes _mysql_ variable ?

Comment: That won't work if `Main` is the literal top-level entry point, which very often must have a constructor without arguments. Fixing `MySQL` seems easier to me.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I've been doing this before, I just thought there's easier way. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @user1587051: The variable is initialized within the constructor. Final variables can only be assigned once, but should allow you to declare it and assign it at a later stage.

Comment: @ShiDoiSi: Yes I do agree. I just did it that way to get the point to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The field `mysql` must get instantiated every time an object of type `Main` is created. When a new `MySQL` instance is created, since it has the field `Main main`, a new `Main` instance is created. `20 goto 10` :-)

In the `MySQL` class, you can avoid creating another `Main` instance in two ways: either make sure that you refer to *static* members of `Main`, or make `MySQL` a *nested* class within `Main`, in which case you don't need the extra field.